# Scroll View not behaving properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a screen on which i am using scroll view.I am having scroll view as the parent view.

**Scroll View constraints**

```
center x to super view 
leading space 
trailing space 
top space to top layout guide ,constant:-64.0
```

Inside scroll view i have a main view.

**Man view constraints**

```
center x to super view 
leading space 
trailing space 
top space 
bottom space,constant:-30
height:30
```

[image]

As you can see the image there is a label below but that label is not visible it is visible when i add the scroll the view.Please tell me how t fit the whole view into screen .Even on iPad it is not correct.

Comment: Can you share hierarchy of Main storyboard -> view controller -> UI elements structure with constraints? that will be helpful.

Comment: How do i share tell me

Comment: Attach image (including constraints) like this https://www.google.co.in/search?q=storyboard+ui+elements+hierarchy&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=590&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIqdvGj72RyAIVSE2OCh2gTQj5#imgrc=TBxMFc6zGL7XBM%3A

Comment: that would too many images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the issue is with scroll view . It's with your VC if you can check the size in size inspector it'll be at 0 below navigation bar.

you should just select your view controller open attribute inspector and deselct **under Top Bars** [image] .

This will set your mainView which is embedded inside your VC to 64 [image: view]

and your scoll view **should be** at 0 Y. as you've alreday set your main view to 64.[image: scroll view]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Actually when i add scroll view it takes automatic spacing of 64 so when i give it top space of -64 then it start just after top bar. & when i deselect the your suggestion then it moves the SV up

Comment: just take my suggestion and place other views at 0 y

Comment: your main view is set to 64 y and grayed out ?

Comment: my scroll view is set to -64 & main view has COSNTRAINTS I MENTIONED IN AQUESTION

Comment: you don't need to set it to -64 as your view is already at 64 that's height of navigationbar. just change it to 0. and i think you'll be good to go

Comment: when i change it to 64 then scroll start below top bar witth top margin of 64

Comment: @deepakkumar I've updated answer  with images of my constraints.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90587/discussion-between-misha-and-deepak-kumar).

Comment: I just shared demo code with you please provide solution if can@Misha

Comment: check your mail. you just needed to set y to 0 and then update your constraints. That's it :)

Comment: Have you tried running it.It shows only splash screen

Comment: did you try setting your VC ?

Comment: i am not able to launch vc from tabs .Don't know why

Comment: in the identity inspector add class name

Comment: done still not working.Ws it running fine on your machine?

Comment: yes itis. other constraint are not set right but I can see label . just open your original code, set value of scroll view to 0. update top constarint where it's set to -64 to 0 as well. and you should be good to go

Comment: ohh my god..it works like magic.Please tell what was that issue?

Comment: just read my comments and answer you'll know. i was telling you this from the very beginning